# Understanding an example involving Left, Right and case statements

Tags: haskell

I'm reading the book "learn you haskell for great good", and one of the examples there confuses me, you can see the example [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses)

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

data LockerState = Taken | Free deriving (Show, Eq)

type Code = String

type LockerMap = Map.Map Int (LockerState, Code)

lockerLookup :: Int -> LockerMap -> Either String Code
lockerLookup lockerNumber map = case Map.lookup lockerNumber map of
    Nothing -> Left $ "Locker" ++ show lockerNumber ++ "doesn't exist"
    Just (state, code) -> if state /= Taken
        then Right code
        else Left $ "Locker" ++ show lockerNumber ++ "is already taken"
{-
lookup :: Ord k => k -> Map k a -> Maybe a
Lookup the value at a key in the map.
The function will return the corresponding value as (Just value), or Nothing if the key isn't in the map.
-}

-- The "::" can be read "has type."
lockers :: LockerMap
lockers = Map.fromList
    [(100,(Taken, "ZD39I"))
    ,(101,(Free, "JAH3I"))
    ,(103,(Free, "IQSA9"))
    ,(105,(Free, "QOTSA"))
    ,(109,(Taken, "893JJ"))
    ,(110,(Taken, "99292"))
    ]
```

But the specific line with `Nothing -> Left` is the one that confuses me. First, I want to know the exactly meaning of the arrow (I can imagine the meaning of it, but I want something more 'academic')

The other part are the words `Left` and `Right`, I don't know if they are using it like `map` which at first looks like a function but it's only a variable name, or if work as code. In that case what do they really do?

UPDATE

I have find [here](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/10_Error_Handling) a great explanation about "Either". I put it here as reference for anyone with the same doubts I had (go to "Either May Be Better than Maybe"). I'm going to put an extract of the text that gave me the final clue I needed, just in case the page dissappear in the future.

"Talking about error handling 'Maybe' is a bit limited. All we know about the failure is that it occurred. In practice, we'd like to know more. So the next step in error handling is to use the 'Either'.

Either is parameterized by two types, not one. A value of the Either type either contains a value of type a or of type b. We can discriminate between the two possibilities by pattern matching on either constructor. Either is mostly used as a generalization of Maybe in which Left not only encodes failure but is accompanied by an error message. Right encodes success and the accompanying value."

Comment: (1) "I can imagine the use of it, but i want something more... academic" -- Don't fall into the trap of expecting everything in Haskell must have a sophisticated mathematical explanation behind it. Sometimes an arrow is just an arrow. (2) "like the word 'map' who at first looks like the function but it's only a variable name" -- `map` is a function, *and* a variable name.

Comment: you could try reading the book anew from the start, see if things become clearer.

Comment: I did it, but I need some better explanation to certain parts

Comment: see also [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#-.3E). also, while you're learning, it might be helpful to use explicit parens instead of `$`. Also, using more white space and putting less stuff on each line might clear up the code, too.

Comment: (as something [like this](https://lpaste.net/5242398113259323392), say).

Comment: Thanks, more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identifiers `Nothing` and `Just` are data constructors for the `Maybe` type, which is given as:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

Data constructors let you work in two directions. You can use them both as values, where you put values into a data constructor:

```
let x = Just 3
let y = Nothing
```

You can also use pattern matching to move values out of a value which has a data constructor:

```
case x of
    Just y -> putStr y
    Nothing -> putStr "Nothing here to see"
```

The arrow itself does not have any particular meaning. It just separates the pattern (like `Just y` or `Nothing`) from the value of the `case` expression when the pattern matches `putStr y` or `putStr "Nothing here to see"`. It is just syntax.

Comment: and 'Left'? how it works in the example?, I know it become from 'Either' but, it's not clear for me their adaptation to the code

Comment: Look at the definition for `Either`, it’s basically the same.

Comment: So, It's just like say, "it's an error, put in left, it's the correct answer put it on Right", it's they only use

Answer (score 2):

`->` merely denotes correspondence between an alternative and the consequent value returned in a single `case` clause.

```
x = 2
y = case x of
    2 -> 4
    5 -> 42
    _ -> 0
```

sets `y` to 4.

`Left` and `Right` are data constructors for `Either`:

```
data Either t u = Left t | Right u
```

Comment: yes, I thought I understood 'Either', but I don't know how they work in the example

Comment: `Either t u` is either something of the shape `Left t` or `Right u`. So `Left` is a constructor or a function, in that case , with type `t -> Either t u` and `Right` is a function `u -> Either t u`.